# What was the name of the crime lord who lived in a replica of the Jedi Temple?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I know that somewhere in Legends there is a crime lord who owned a replica of the Jedi Temple and a large number of Jedi/Sith artifacts.

What I have forgotten is a name, location, or in what source this occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character [Grakkus Jahibakti Tingi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grakkus_Jahibakti_Tingi), AKA Grakkus the Hutt, had a [palace](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Palace_of_Grakkus_the_Hutt) on the Hutt world of Nar Shaddaa, which contained a variety of Jedi artefacts from before the Great Purge including several holocrons. Grakkus appears in multiple Canon comics, while his palace appears in: [*Star Wars 9*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015)_9), [*10*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015)_10), [*11*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015)_11), and [*12*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(2015)_12).

While his palace is not an exact replica of the Jedi Temple on Coruscant, it is a similar ziggurat-inspired design:
[image: Grakkus' Palace]

Comment: While interesting, I am reasonably sure that what I was recalling was a stone building, most likely on a Hutt world, because all the best crimes happen in Hutt Space.

Comment: Well now are you positive it was the Jedi Temple? There was a bar/nightclub venue in one book that duplicated Jabba's Palace right down to a replica of Han in carbonite.

Comment: @TheAmusedMuse I think I found the correct character after a new search attempt. He's actually a Canon character, not Legends, hence my initial issue. I altered the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.